# Filestreaming 1 file on webapp under heavy load (Memory Management)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory-management

I am currently using a single file in my web app to pull tabulation areas (zips, lats, longs, etc) and came across a potential problem while debugging.

When I rapidly switched between two actions in my web app (both bringing this text file into a filestream) I got the typical "This file is being used by another process" error. I cleaned up my code some more and disposed of said filestreams as quickly as possible and can not reproduce this error anymore.

That's fine if one user were using the site but if I have potential thousands I see this being a big problem.

My question is: **How can I make sure this does not happen under a heavy traffic load?**

I'm spitting out idea's I've had no matter how stupid or impractical they may sound. I have not chosen to go with these ideas for those reasons and that is why I am asking for advice on here.

- Having multiple text files and moving to the next when one is in use
- Creating a copy of the file per request and getting rid of it after its job is done
- Moving the data to a DB

I have tried the DB approach but find that getting all the data into memory takes 3-4 seconds because there is such a large amount of data. A file stream takes less than a second to a second tops.

Comment: Why not have a static class that contains the contents of this file, so you are only having to read it in once.  Then, that class is available to everyone as long as the app pool doesnt reset?

Comment: @Tommy I have that functionality on two other files that I use alot but some how never thought of applying that to the tabulation areas *face palm* You sir, just saved me tons of processing time :)

Comment: Haha - I hate when I do that in my projects.  I can post that comment as an answer if you feel it better answers your question in this instance

Comment: Both answer my question; however, this one would definitely be the most efficient way to handle my specific scenario. Go ahead and answer it if you like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this data sounds like it is mainly read-only across all users of your application, you could create a static class to hold the data.  This way, you only have to read the data in once and it will be available to all users of your application until the application pool resets.  Using a static class and constructor, you should be able to do a single read with the ability for any user to access the data.

```
public static class Tabulardata{

      private readonly object Data;        

      static TabularData(){
           Data = //read and process file data
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just reading a file you can simply pass the `FileShare.Read` argument into your `FileStream` constructor to easily allow for multiple processes to read the file.

The following FileStream constructor opens an existing file and grants read-only access to other users (Read).

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

A typical use of this enumeration is to define whether two processes can simultaneously read from the same file. For example, if a file is opened and Read is specified, other users can open the file for reading but not for writing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx